# Using a rails delete method in an html link?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I need to change this to HTML and have no idea how to put the delete route in a normal a tag, any ideas? Thanks

```
        <li><%= link_to "Link", user_photo_pin_path(user_id: @user.id, photo_id: @photo.id, id: {{id}} ) , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Quieres borrar esto?'} %></li>
```

Comment: Use the erb code you've got, see what it renders and then copy that. Hard coding things like this is probably a bad idea - look into using partials or something similar perhaps?

Comment: `<a href="your_path" data-confirm="Quieres borrar esto?" data-method="delete">Link</a>` just inspect the rendered link in browser

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the data-method...thought it didn't work.

Comment: can you check your server log and see what controller action the current html is mapped to?

Comment: Method `delete` may produce issues with older versions of IE (v8 and below)...it will send `get` request...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like "pry-rails" or "debugger" gems. Set up "debugger" method in your view and execute any of `ActionView:Helpers` like `link_to` or `form_tag` and see what html returned by this methods.